# How to Specify vpcEndpointIds in Open api specification for an Apigateway PRIVATE api in SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, openapi

I have a SAM template file where i defined my Api as a **AWS::Serverless::Api** resource.
The api is supposed to have an **EndpointConfiguration: PRIVATE**
Unlike **AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi, AWS::Serverless::Api** supports only a String value for an EndpointConfiguration.

For **AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi:**
I can add 2 properties
**Types** : PRIVATE
**vpcEndpointIds** : []

but for **AWS::Serverless::Api**
I only have one String property that is **PRIVATE**

As I searched for how to configure **vpcEndpointIds** I found :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-endpoint-configuration.html

And this documentation says that **vpcEndpointIds** should be defined under **"x-amazon-apigateway-endpoint-configuration"** in an open api specification document.

but I am not able to find any example on how exactly it should be defined neither in AWS docs nor in open api docs.

Open api doc says it should be defined under **server** object which I tried and neither worked.

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This option is available with [CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apigateway-restapi-endpointconfiguration.html) but SAM currently does not support defining the VPC endpoint under EndpointConfiguration.

This feature of associating the VPC endpoint was recently added so I think SAM hasn't been updated for it yet. There is a [feature request](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/pull/1524) for it, so I expect it to be implemented soon.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply Suraj.

I found the right way to do it in SAM. As you mentioned it is not directly available in SAM as an option. But you can achieve this in the api open api definition document as follows under servers object:

```
        servers:
      - url: "https://apiname.execute-api.region.aws.com/{basePath}"
        variables:
          basePath:
            default: "/stagename"
        x-amazon-apigateway-endpoint-configuration:
          vpcEndpointIds:
            - !Ref vpcEndpointId
```

For those who are experiencing the same issue Please remember if you are using swagger 2.0 specification then the property needs to be at a different level.
Find it here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-endpoint-configuration.html